# Export glm train fit summary from caret with stargazer?

Tags: r, model, r-caret, summary, stargazer

I want to use the package "stargazer" in order to export the fit summary of a train with caret.

e.g.

```
LogReg <- train(
Target ~ .,
data = DecileFramesTrain[[i]], method="glm", family="binomial",
trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, verboseIter = TRUE)
)
```

and then

```
stargazer(summary(LogReg), title="Coefficients of (binomial) logistic regression fit", align=TRUE, summary=TRUE)
```

However, I receive the following response:

```
"Error: Unrecognized object type."
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I could not find a solution online. Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Tobster18  Welcome to stackoverflow  How can I improve my answer to get it marked as accepted?

Comment: Sorry for the late response :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to get a stargazer summary of the final model produced by caret:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench) # for PimaIndiansDiabetes data
library(stargazer)

data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

LogReg <- train(diabetes ~ ., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="glm",family="binomial", 
                trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, verboseIter = TRUE))

glm1 <- glm(diabetes ~ ., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, family="binomial")
LogReg$finalModel$call <- glm1$call
stargazer(LogReg$finalModel)
```

The `stargazer` function uses the `call` parameter to check for model type.
It was missing from the final caret model.  The glm `call` parameter belongs to the call class.  See `?call` in an R session for further details.  The second to last line in the code above adds the `call` parameter to the final caret model.

Note 1: Strictly speaking the `call` parameter added to the final caret model is incorrect because of the caret cross validation.

Note 2: I've not checked the LaTeX code produced by stargazer.